# Grails jms queue annotation fails with final parameter

Tags: grails, annotations, queue, jms

I am using the annotation grails.plugin.jms.Queue from the Grails JMS plugin, but I can't figure out how to use a variable as the value of the name attribute.

like this:

```
private static final inDebit = ConfigurationHolder.config.Q_IN_DEBIT

@Queue(name = inDebit )
```

Which gives me the following error:

> Attribute 'name' should have type 'java.lang.String'; but found type 'java.lang.Object' in @grails.plugin.jms.Queue

I am using
Grails 1.3.7, Grails JMS Plugin 1.1

Looks to me like the `inDebit` variable loses its type somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

It didn't lose its type, you never specified it. Change to

```
private static final String inDebit = ConfigurationHolder.config.Q_IN_DEBIT
```

Groovy can infer the type at runtime, but as you have it it's just `Object` and that's what the compiler sees.

Answer (score 1):

Static holders are being [deprecated in 1.4](http://grails.org/1.4.0.M1+Release+Notes).  You should use [grailsApplication](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/grailsApplication.html) instead:

```
def grailsApplication
private static final String inDebit = grailsApplication.config.Q_IN_DEBIT
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation in Groovy annotations handling:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-3278

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer to the question, but I think this is what you really want to do:

```
@Queue(name = '$queue.key.in.config')
```

And put `jms.destinations.queue.key.in.config=ActualQueueName` in your Config.groovy

Check the grails jms docs here: [serviceMethodListeners](http://gpc.github.io/jms/latest/guide/receivingMessages.html#serviceMethodListeners)
Scroll down to the section labelled "Defining the Queue names and Subscriber topics through configuration"